# Left join with dplyr and conditional

Tags: r, join, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes:

**dists**:

```
label1 label2      dist     sameCol ID1  ID2
193    194       0.7219847      NA  N53 <NA>
193    195       0.5996300   FALSE  N53  N43
193    196       0.2038451   FALSE  N5  N45
194    195       0.2190454      NA <NA>  N43
194    196       0.8894645      NA <NA>  N45
195    196       0.7910169    TRUE  N38  N5
```

**networkDistances**:

```
ID1  ID2   colony   value    networkDist
N38  N5     10      0.05           1
N36  N5     10      0.03           1
N4   N3     12      10.00          1
N4   N5     12      10.00          1
N4   N15     12     5.00           1
N15  N14     12     5.00           1
```

I am trying to join them, IF `dists$sameCol == TRUE` && ID1 and ID2 match, then paste the columns from networkDistances (all other rows should be NA), to look like:

```
label1 label2      dist     sameCol ID1  ID2   colony   value    networkDist
193    194       0.7219847      NA  N53 <NA>   NA        NA            NA
193    195       0.5996300   FALSE  N53  N43   NA        NA            NA
193    196       0.2038451   FALSE  N5   N45   NA        NA            NA
194    195       0.2190454      NA <NA>  N43   NA        NA            NA
194    196       0.8894645      NA <NA>  N45   NA        NA            NA
195    196       0.7910169    TRUE  N38  N5    10       0.05           1
```

I have tried these and they are not working, they paste some info into rows where `dists$sameCol == FALSE`

```
r <- left_join(dists, networkDistances, by = c("ID1" = "ID1", "ID2" = "ID2")) 

r <- left_join(dists, networkDistances, by = c("ID1" = "ID1", "ID2" = "ID2")) %>%
  mutate(networkDist = case_when(sameCol  %in% T ~ networkDist))

r <-dists %>% 
  left_join(networkDistances, by = c("ID1","ID2"))%>%
  mutate(networkDist = case_when(sameCol== T ~ networkDist))
```

Comment: based on your supplied examples, `r <- left_join(dists, networkDistances, by = c("ID1", "ID2"))` produces the required outcome - there are no rows where `sameCol` would make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to merging, add a `sameCol` column with all `TRUE` values to `networkDists` and use it as an additional key:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  dists,
  mutate(networkDistances, sameCol = TRUE),
  by = c("ID1", "ID2", "sameCol")
)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 9
  label1 label2  dist sameCol ID1   ID2   colony value networkDist
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1    193    194 0.722 NA      N53   <NA>      NA NA             NA
2    193    195 0.600 FALSE   N53   N43       NA NA             NA
3    193    196 0.204 FALSE   N5    N45       NA NA             NA
4    194    195 0.219 NA      <NA>  N43       NA NA             NA
5    194    196 0.889 NA      <NA>  N45       NA NA             NA
6    195    196 0.791 TRUE    N38   N5        10  0.05           1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r <- left_join(dists, networkDistances, by = c("ID1", "ID2"))
r[r$sameCol != TRUE | is.na(r$sameCol), c("colony", "value", "networkDist")] <- NA
```

First line does the join (and for your example, achieves the required output).  Second line amends those columns to NA for any non-TRUE`sameCol`, including those with `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

First check the condition, then do the merge. I added some more rows to the example to make it clear it omits the negative case.

```
dists
  label1 label2      dist sameCol  ID1  ID2
1    193    194 0.7219847      NA  N53 <NA>
2    193    195 0.5996300   FALSE  N53  N43
3    193    196 0.2038451   FALSE   N5  N45
4    194    195 0.2190454      NA <NA>  N43
5    194    196 0.8894645      NA <NA>  N45
6    195    196 0.7910169    TRUE  N38   N5
7    195    196 0.7910169   FALSE  N38   N5
8    195    196 0.7910169    TRUE  N36   N5
```

get the subset

```
dists_flt <- dists[c(with(dists, which(!(ID1 %in% networkDistances$ID1 & ID2 %in% networkDistances$ID2))),
    with(dists, which((ID1 %in% networkDistances$ID1 & ID2 %in% networkDistances$ID2 & sameCol == T)))),]
```

with **base R**

```
merge(dists_flt, networkDistances, c("ID1", "ID2"), all.x = T)
   ID1  ID2 label1 label2      dist sameCol colony value networkDist
1 <NA>  N43    194    195 0.2190454      NA     NA    NA          NA
2 <NA>  N45    194    196 0.8894645      NA     NA    NA          NA
3  N36   N5    195    196 0.7910169    TRUE     10  0.03           1
4  N38   N5    195    196 0.7910169    TRUE     10  0.05           1
5   N5  N45    193    196 0.2038451   FALSE     NA    NA          NA
6  N53 <NA>    193    194 0.7219847      NA     NA    NA          NA
7  N53  N43    193    195 0.5996300   FALSE     NA    NA          NA
```

or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(dists_flt, networkDistances, c("ID1", "ID2"))
  label1 label2      dist sameCol  ID1  ID2 colony value networkDist
1    193    194 0.7219847      NA  N53 <NA>     NA    NA          NA
2    193    195 0.5996300   FALSE  N53  N43     NA    NA          NA
3    193    196 0.2038451   FALSE   N5  N45     NA    NA          NA
4    194    195 0.2190454      NA <NA>  N43     NA    NA          NA
5    194    196 0.8894645      NA <NA>  N45     NA    NA          NA
6    195    196 0.7910169    TRUE  N38   N5     10  0.05           1
7    195    196 0.7910169    TRUE  N36   N5     10  0.03           1
```

##### Extended data

```
dists <- structure(list(label1 = c(193L, 193L, 193L, 194L, 194L, 195L,
195L, 195L), label2 = c(194L, 195L, 196L, 195L, 196L, 196L, 196L,
196L), dist = c(0.7219847, 0.59963, 0.2038451, 0.2190454, 0.8894645,
0.7910169, 0.7910169, 0.7910169), sameCol = c(NA, FALSE, FALSE,
NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), ID1 = c("N53", "N53", "N5", "<NA>",
"<NA>", "N38", "N38", "N36"), ID2 = c("<NA>", "N43", "N45", "N43",
"N45", "N5", "N5", "N5")), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")

networkDistances <- structure(list(ID1 = c("N38", "N36", "N4", "N4", "N4", "N15"),
    ID2 = c("N5", "N5", "N3", "N5", "N15", "N14"), colony = c(10L,
    10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), value = c(0.05, 0.03, 10, 10, 5,
    5), networkDist = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```